# SQL Server: Display 0 in Group by with Distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I've got a table with a lot of entries per day. Each entry has got a "Level". Now what I'am trying to do is, to select foreach day how many records exists with a Level. The Levels can be different so first of all I need to select distinct all levels and the show for each day how many records foreach level are there. If there are none records by a level for a day, the value should be 0.

so to illustrate my needs: 
my table has the following content

```
¦Date        ¦ Level ¦ RecId ¦
------------------------------
¦2014-06-18  ¦  1    ¦  1
¦2014-06-18  ¦  1    ¦  2
¦2014-06-18  ¦  2    ¦  3
¦2014-11-06  ¦  1    ¦  4
¦2014-11-11  ¦  2    ¦  5
¦2014-11-13  ¦  3    ¦  6
```

what I'd like to have is the following:

```
¦Date        ¦ Level ¦ CountOfRecords ¦
--------------------------------------
¦2014-06-18  ¦  1    ¦  2
¦2014-06-18  ¦  2    ¦  1
¦2014-08-18  ¦  3    ¦  0
¦2014-11-06  ¦  1    ¦  1
¦2014-11-06  ¦  2    ¦  0
¦2014-11-06  ¦  3    ¦  0
¦2014-11-11  ¦  1    ¦  0
¦2014-11-11  ¦  2    ¦  1
¦2014-11-11  ¦  3    ¦  0
¦2014-11-13  ¦  1    ¦  0
¦2014-11-13  ¦  2    ¦  0
¦2014-11-13  ¦  3    ¦  1
```

The reason why I need that is to display these values in a line chart and each level will be a line.

Thanks for your help, while I'm still going on with google...

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT T.[Date], 
           T.[Level], 
           COALESCE(COUNT(D.[Level]),0) AS CountOfRecords
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT B.Date, A.[Level] 
          FROM tablename AS A 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] 
                            FROM tablename) AS B ON 1=1
          ) 
          AS T LEFT JOIN tablename AS D ON T.[Level] = D.[Level] 
                                           AND T.[Date] = D.[Date]
    GROUP BY T.[Date], T.[Level]
    ORDER BY T.[Date], T.[Level]
```

[test is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395213)

Comment: `INNER JOIN ON 1=1` is just overcomplication for `cross join`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri `Cross Join` can be applied as in my post, as in your post, using comma separator (table1, table), and also using `Cross Apply` without `search_condition`. Execution plan for all joins listed above will be the same. so this is not over-complication, such way of coding is just matter of habit.

Comment: @Vasily, I agree. It is just a bad practice to do so. With comma it is old deprecated synrax from 1990. Cross apply will be more difficult to read. The natural way to produce cartesian result is cross join.

Answer (score 2):

Produce `cross join` of distinct `dates` and `levels` and then `left join` on actual table:

```
;with cte1 as(select distinct level from tablename),
      cte2 as(select distinct date from tablename)
select c1.level, 
       c2.date,
       count(distinct t.RecId) as CountOfRecords 
from cte1 c1
cross join cte2 c2
left join tablename t on t.date = c2.date and t.level = c1.level
group by c1.level, c2.date
```

**EDIT:**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Date DATE ,
      Level INT ,
      RecId INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '2014-06-18', 1, 1 ),
        ( '2014-06-18', 1, 2 ),
        ( '2014-06-18', 2, 3 ),
        ( '2014-11-06', 1, 4 ),
        ( '2014-11-11', 2, 5 ),
        ( '2014-11-13', 3, 6 )

;with cte1 as(select distinct level from @t),
      cte2 as(select distinct date from @t)
select c1.level, 
       c2.date,
       count(distinct t.RecId) as CountOfRecords 
from cte1 c1
cross join cte2 c2
left join @t t on t.date = c2.date and t.level = c1.level
group by c1.level, c2.date
```

Output:

```
level   date    CountOfRecords
1       2014-06-18  2
2       2014-06-18  1
3       2014-06-18  0
1       2014-11-06  1
2       2014-11-06  0
3       2014-11-06  0
1       2014-11-11  0
2       2014-11-11  1
3       2014-11-11  0
1       2014-11-13  0
2       2014-11-13  0
3       2014-11-13  1
```

Comment: Thank you where much for the quick answer. Unfortunately it produces not exactly the right output. The output for CountOfRecords is one even if there are 4 Records for this day with this level. But anyway the answer of Vasily worked perfectly.

Comment: @M.G, I don't know what you are talking about, but for your data the output is exactly the same as yours!

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I did a mistake by modifying your code for my database. Now it works also. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Date]
      , [level_ordinal] AS [level]
      , (SELECT COUNT([RecId]) 
            FROM [entries] AS E2 
            WHERE E2.[Level] = L.[level_ordinal]
                AND E2.[Date] = E1.[Date]) AS CountOfRecords
  FROM [entries] AS E1
  CROSS JOIN [entries_levels] AS L
```

with:

```
CREATE TABLE entries_levels
(
    [level_ordinal] [int] NULL
)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO entries_levels VALUES (1), (2), (3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer of @Vasily worked perfectly

Comment: It's at least unpolite not voting my answer, considered that it's faster (compare execution plans). 

Ok, the @Vasily answer it's charmy because not using a second table (very very nice @Vasily) but what about readability? 

And hard-coding levels with the second table it's a matter of good design, considered that surely their values are related to your "business logic"

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Create Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
(
Date DATETIME,
Level INT,
RecID INT
)
```

Insert Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
VALUES
('2014-06-18', '1', '1'),
('2014-06-18', '1', '2'),
('2014-08-18', '2', '3'),
('2014-11-06', '1', '4'),
('2014-11-11', '2', '5'),
('2014-11-13', '3', '6')
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Level,
    COUNT(RecID) AS [CountOfRecords]
FROM NewTable
GROUP BY Date, Level
```

Output:

```
======================
|Date      |Lvl|Count|
|2014-06-18|1  |2    |
|2014-11-06|1  |1    |
|2014-08-18|2  |1    |
|2014-11-11|2  |1    |
|2014-11-13|3  |1    |
======================
```

PS: I think you need to re-read your sample data VS your expected output as you have iterated level 1-3 for date 2014-06-18 but in one line you have 2014-08-18 and continued that as level 3 so the count in incorrect no?

Comment: This was exactly what i had, but unfortunately this is not what i was expecting to have. Your correct, there was a litte type error. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I'm glad you got your answer.